# Kedushas Levi's Eight Segulos of Chanukah

Tags: chanuka, segulah

In the past few years, each Chanukah I have received a list, attributed to the Kedushas Levi, of Eight Segulos for the eight nights of Chanukah, with each Segula corresponding to the number of candles lit that night. This year, I was sent the same idea again in a newsletter:
[image]

> The Kedushas Levi says that women have a tremendous ability to gain from the lights of Chanukah. He states that each night of Chanukah is mesugal for different things for women to daven for.
>
> 1st night – Not to be lonely or depressed;
>
> 2nd night – Shidduchim and Shalom Bayis;
>
> 3rd night – Healthy, happy and good children. (The Chasam Sofer says when you cry in front of the candles – you can be sure your teffilos will be answered);
>
> 4th night – (Four Imahos) To be a conventional woman within her own space who is true to her essence;
>
> 5th night – (Chamisha Chumshei Torah) Daven your husband and children should be talmidei chachamim. (By the 5th night, more of the menorah is lit up. You can daven for more revelation and light in your life);
>
> 6th night – Simcha. (You can have everything and still be sad, so this is an opportunity to daven for simcha);
>
> 7th night – Blissful Shabbos Kodesh infused with zmiros, divrei torah by your seuda. Shabbos is source of all bracha;
>
> 8th (Zos) night – Mesugal for barren women. (The number eight is above nature. According to Kabbalah: because the world was created in seven days so the number eight is considered beyond creation). Very powerful day to daven for yourself and others who weren’t yet zocheh to children.
>
> The Kedushas Levi says if you are planning to start something new, if you start on Chanukah it will surely be blessed.

I have tried searching for the source text upon which this is supposedly based, but I was unable to find anything similar in the writings of the Kedushas Levi on Chanukah.

Is this idea correctly attributed to the Kedushas Levi and if so, where can the original text be found?

Comment: Maybe check his peirush on vayeishv,miketz

Comment: Hebrew books #50006 has a section in the end on Chanukah not sure if that contains this, though. Wiki text also has that

Comment: Sounds very fake

Comment: Not here https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/קדושת_לוי/קדושות_לחנוכה